# How to pass data from editText.text to another activity in Xamarin Android when button is clicked

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin

From `MainActivity.cs` to `AnotherActivity.cs`

```
  public static string hisname;
    public static string hername;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Register1);
        // Create your application here
        EditText her = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextHername);
        EditText his = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextUrname);
        //RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
        //anim.setInterpolator
        //anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        //anim.Duration(700);
        //splash.StartAnimation(anim);


        WindowRotationAnimation q = new WindowRotationAnimation();
        Button getStarted = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        getStarted.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CalculateActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("yourname", ""+hisname);
            intent.PutExtra("GFname", "" + hername);
            StartActivity(intent);

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your editext is there in Activity A and you need data in Activity B?

Comment: You aren't setting the `hisname` and `hername` variables to the values from the `EditText` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following

```
var herName = her.text;


vad hisName = his.text;
```

and add into `intent.putextra` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static string hisname;
public static string hername;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Register1);
    // Create your application here
    EditText her = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextHername);
    EditText his = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextUrname);
    //RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
    //anim.setInterpolator
    //anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    //anim.Duration(700);
    //splash.StartAnimation(anim);


    WindowRotationAnimation q = new WindowRotationAnimation();
    Button getStarted = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
    getStarted.Click += delegate
    {
        hisname=his.Text;
        hername=her.Text;
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CalculateActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("yourname", hisname);
        intent.PutExtra("GFname",  hername);
        StartActivity(intent);

    };
}
```

inside your OnCreate of the AnotherActivity.cs you can get these strings like this:

```
string hisname=Intent.GetStringExtra ("yourname");
string hername=Intent.GetStringExtra ("GFname"); // Seriously :P
```

This is actually an easy solution if you wanted this one. I would suggest you should research first before you post questions

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

pass data from your_first_activity to your_next_activity

```
Intent i = new Intent (Application.Context, typeof(your_next_activity));
i.PutExtra ("item", "item_to_pass");
StartActivity (i);
```

retrieve data bundle passed from your_first_activity on your_next_activity

```
string item = Intent.GetStringExtra("item");
```